# Weird line-break in span

Tags: css, html, firefox

For some reason, the following HTML snippet wraps the `%` sign onto a new line (FireFox only):

```
<span class="label">
    <input type="radio" />
    <span>
        <span>1,22</span>
        <span>%</span>
        <br />
   </span>
</span>
```

And css:

```
.label {display: inline-block;}
```

[image]

Its a snippet, so it doesn't make much sense on its own, but I don't understand why this is happening, I think its valid HTML5. Can someone explain what the problem is with this snippet, because it works in Chrome and not in FireFx ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gc0sq29k/10/)

Comment: It's looking fine for me in the DEMO in Chrome 40. Is it a specific browser that's causing your problem?

Comment: Why are you using 2 span tags for this? Would it not be easier to use 1 and add or subtract the % symbol in your js?

Comment: In the html where this snippet is extracted from, the first `span` is actually a `label`. Note that this problem only occurs in FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox renders this incorrectly.

[**Inline blocks**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width) should use the **[shrink-to-fit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float)** algorithm:

> calculate the ***preferred width*** by formatting the content without
> breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur,
>
> calculate the ***preferred minimum width***, e.g., by trying all possible
> line breaks.
>
> find the ***available width***: in this case, this is the width of the
> containing block minus the used values of 'margin-left',
> 'border-left-width', 'padding-left', 'padding-right',
> 'border-right-width', 'margin-right', and the widths of any relevant
> scroll bars.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is:
>
> min(max(preferred minimum width,available width), preferred width)

In this case:

1. `preferred width` is the width without any word wrapping.
2. `preferred minimum width` is the width of the widest element, in this case "1,22."
3. `available width` is the width of the document body, in this case 100%.

`min(max(preferred minimum width,available width), preferred width)` should therefore be equal to `preferred width`.

You can fix Firefox's behavior by changing your HTML or by using `white-space:nowrap`.

But I have another alternative:  `br` is an **[inline element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-BR)**, but changing it to a block element fixes the problem.

Doing so shouldn't have an impact on any other `br` elements in your HTML (that I can think of).

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tkwkv0xo/)

Answer (score 3):

Adding `white-space:nowrap;` should fix it:

```
.label {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gc0sq29k/11/)**

Comment: But could you explain to me why Chrome displays this snippet just fine and FF does not ? Because there are many solutions, for example, you could change the `.label` css into: `display: inline`

Comment: As far as I can tell, it looks like the trailing `<br />` in FF allows the rendering engine to create a new line and shrink the inline-block box enough for the % to drop. Other browsers appear to ignore the empty newline.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is Firefox is interpreting your second span as being inline with the `<br/>` element. Try putting the `<br/>` element outside of the span wrapping the 2 spans like so:

```
<span class="label">
    <input type="radio" />
    <span>
      <span>1,22</span>
      <span>%</span>

    </span>
    <br />
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gc0sq29k/12/

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing this out! But does that make any sense ?